# R: Group by data every N months

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have data from 2016-01-01 to 2017-07-30. I want to group_by data every three months and summarize. It's hard to show the entire data since it won't fit here. I generally use `lubridate` and `dplyr` for data manipulation but I am unable to figure out how to roll up data every three months. The pseudo code of what I am trying to accomplish is as below:

```
df$month <- month(as.Date(df$date))
df$year <- year(as.Date(df$date))
df %>% group_by(month + "3 Months", year) %>% summarise(n = sum(pageviews))
```

Can you please suggest me a simple way to do this? I know it's very simple using `dplyr`. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: don't you have functions to get quarters in lubridate ?

Comment: Yes, there is a function in lubridate and thank you for pointing that out. But, what if I want to try different n months or days. I am looking for a more generalized answer.

Comment: try `df$month_group <- (df$month-reference_month) %/% 3` and group by month_group

Comment: use a lubridate function tu substract the months instead,or it won't work cross year

Comment: No, this is grouping data into the groups of 0, 1 and 2. Instead, I want data grouped by every three months from 2016-01 to 2017-07.

Comment: You should add a reproducible example and the expected output

Comment: okay. I'll edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(dategroup = lubridate::floor_date(date, "2 months")) %>%
  group_by(dategroup) %>% ...
```

`floor_date`, `ceiling_date`, and `round_date` accept as arguments:

> a character string specifying the time unit or a multiple of a unit
>   to be rounded to. Valid base units are second, minute, hour, day,
>   week, month, bimonth, quarter, halfyear, or year. Arbitrary unique
>   English abbreviations as in period constructor are also supported.
>   Rounding to multiple of units (except weeks) is supported from
>   v1.6.0.

Comment: Voo!! Thank you so much. You made my life so easy.